# Column Does Not Exist Django M2M

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, many-to-many

I thought I created a fairly simple models for my Django app, but for some reason I cannot add m2m fields to Company model objects. Here is the [stacktrace](http://dpaste.com/hold/1692223/)

**Snippet from models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    notes = models.TextField()
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=125)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, related_name='c+')
```

**Snippet from inspectdb**

```
class WorkCompany(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'work_company'

class WorkCompanyContacts(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(WorkCompany)
    contacts_id = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'work_company_contacts'

class WorkContact(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    notes = models.TextField()
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'work_contact'
```

**Sql Dump**

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "work_span" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "start_time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "end_time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "work_task_hours" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "task_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "span_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "work_span" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    UNIQUE ("task_id", "span_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "work_task" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "slug" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "description" text NOT NULL,
    "notes" text NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE "work_task_hours" ADD CONSTRAINT "task_id_refs_id_4a2c3ab2" FOREIGN KEY ("task_id") REFERENCES "work_task" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE TABLE "work_contact" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "phone" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "notes" text NOT NULL,
    "job_title" varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "work_company_contacts" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "company_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "contact_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "work_contact" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    UNIQUE ("company_id", "contact_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "work_company" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "slug" varchar(125) NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE "work_company_contacts" ADD CONSTRAINT "company_id_refs_id_82bae779" FOREIGN KEY ("company_id") REFERENCES "work_company" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE TABLE "work_day_tasks" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "day_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "task_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "work_task" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    UNIQUE ("day_id", "task_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "work_day" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "company_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "work_company" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    "hourly_rate" numeric(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    "date" date NOT NULL,
    "notes" text NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE "work_day_tasks" ADD CONSTRAINT "day_id_refs_id_209846d6" FOREIGN KEY ("day_id") REFERENCES "work_day" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE TABLE "work_month_work_days" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "month_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "day_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "work_day" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    UNIQUE ("month_id", "day_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "work_month" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "month" varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE "work_month_work_days" ADD CONSTRAINT "month_id_refs_id_27ea75cb" FOREIGN KEY ("month_id") REFERENCES "work_month" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

COMMIT;
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** I removed all my south migrations and tried again, and things seem to work properly. My guess is the schema migrations left my database in a strange state. Here are the migrations that I removed to fix the problem: [0001_initial.py](https://github.com/tomleo/invoice/blob/c034172fc56dc6e072ad7f2e67aab96a301b941f/invoice/work/migrations/0001_initial.py) and [0002_auto__del_contacts__add_contact.py](https://github.com/tomleo/invoice/blob/c034172fc56dc6e072ad7f2e67aab96a301b941f/invoice/work/migrations/0002_auto__del_contacts__add_contact.py)

Comment: According to stacktrace, maybe this is related to admin definitions?

Comment: @eran I removed my south migrations and things seem to work properly. Still haven't tried to figure out how/why the migrations caused this problem.